# NameError at / uninitialized constant Sass::SyntaxError

Tags: ruby, sinatra, textmate, sass, padrino

I am using Padrino and when I try to specify my application.sass file I get this error `NameError at / uninitialized constant Sass::SyntaxError`

I thought I might have something missing, so I checked out the sample_blog application at their GIT to verify my SASS is working correct. It was working correct and the blog app was running fine. Then I decided to change a line in the blog's application.sass and I got this error.

I am using TextMate to edit the file.

Weird indeed, any advices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the issue is simple and already fixed in Padrino edge. Basically rename `lib/sass.rb` to `lib/sass_plugin.rb`. Check out the issue here: http://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues/closed#issue/94

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you get started using Padrino. Feel free to pop into #padrino on freenode irc for help too!